# Compile vrplayer project But can not pass, pls some advice.thanks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I was compiling the vrplayer project, but I get compiling errors (see [here](http://pastebin.com/Zv3T22pV)).

The major error is:

```
Error       The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe" /T ps_2_0 /E main /Fo"C:\VR\vrplayer\VrPlayer.Distortions\VrPlayer.Distortions.Barrel\BarrelEffect.ps" "C:\VR\vrplayer\VrPlayer.Distortions\VrPlayer.Distortions.Barrel\Barrel.fx"" exited with code 3.  VrPlayer.Distortions.Barrel    

Error       The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe" /T ps_2_0 /E main /Fo"C:\VR\vrplayer\VrPlayer.Distortions\VrPlayer.Distortions.Pincushion\PincushionEffect.ps" "C:\VR\vrplayer\VrPlayer.Distortions\VrPlayer.Distortions.Pincushion\Pincushion.fx"" exited with code 3.  VrPlayer.Distortions.Pincushion
```

Comment: Windows error code 3 is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`. Check your paths.

Comment: Hi Ian Kemp. You are right, Project directory so long.Thanks Ian Kemp.

Comment: so windows error code need keep https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx